# Prevent row selection in Ag Grid for some columns

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have an Ag Grid table. In that table one pinned column is with action buttons (like edit row, print row item, open in popup, etc). I want to prevent row selection when user clicks on any cell in column with action buttons, but at the same time I need common row multiSelection behaviour with Shift button for all other columns. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the onCellClicked event of the Ag-Grid API. In the event callback, you can check the column that was clicked, and if it is the column with the action buttons, you can call the stopPropagation() method on the event object to prevent the row from being selected. For all other columns, you can continue to allow the default row selection behavior.

```
const gridOptions = {
    
    onCellClicked: (event) => {
        if (event.column.colId === 'actionColumnId') {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
};
```

For the Multi-Selection behavior with shift button, you could enable the `suppressRowClickSelection` flag on the grid options and handle the multi-selection by your own by listening to the 'rowSelected' event and use the shift button detection or programatically change the selection via the API.

```
const gridOptions = {
    
    suppressRowClickSelection: true,
    onRowSelected:(event)=>{
    //Check if the shift button is pressed and act accordingly
    }
};
```